# sql insert multiple rows with inner selects

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I need to insert multiple rows , but some of the data have to come from inner select 
i having problem to construct the right sql statement for example i have :

```
insert into game_friends(
game_users_id,
game_users_id_name,
created_to_app_users_id,
created_to_app_users_id_name
) VALUES  ......
```

now the problematic part is that the  created_to_app_users_id_name and game_users_id_name i can get only by using select like this:

```
SELECT app_users_game_users_id_name
FROM `app_users` WHERE app_users_game_users_id = $game_users_id
```

and

```
SELECT app_users_created_to_app_users_id_name  
FROM `app_users` 
WHERE app_users_created_to_app_users_id = $created_to_app_users_id
```

how can i combine it to one sql statement using mysql

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to all for answering , but i guess didnt explain my problem right ...
i need to insert multiple rows that means i will have like 5-7 game_users_id coming 
and it needs in the end look like ( with out the select here .. )

```
insert into game_friends(
    game_users_id,
    game_users_id_name,
    created_to_app_users_id,
    created_to_app_users_id_name
    )  
VALUES
  ($game_users_id, app_users_created_to_app_users_id_name, $created_to_app_users_id,app_users_created_to_app_users_id_name ),
  ($game_users_id, app_users_created_to_app_users_id_name, $created_to_app_users_id,app_users_created_to_app_users_id_name ),
  ($game_users_id, app_users_created_to_app_users_id_name, $created_to_app_users_id,app_users_created_to_app_users_id_name ),
  ($game_users_id, app_users_created_to_app_users_id_name, $created_to_app_users_id,app_users_created_to_app_users_id_name );
```

where each Values entry need to be composed from select.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for PHP:

```
$query = "insert into game_friends(
 game_users_id,
 game_users_id_name,
 created_to_app_users_id,
 created_to_app_users_id_name
) SELECT
 app_users_game_users_id,
 app_users_game_users_id_name,
 app_users_created_to_app_users_id,
 app_users_created_to_app_users_id_name
FROM `app_users` WHERE
app_users_game_users_id = $game_users_id
AND
app_users_created_to_app_users_id = $created_to_app_users_id";
```

Comment: Leaves some nice SQL injection holes if $game_users_id and/or $created_to_app_users_id can be controlled by the user in any way. User prepared statements whenever possible to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: @JamesOltmans Thanks for the observation it's actually a variable so I tried to use the variable that he mentioned from the question so I suppose that the variables were already cleaned somehow removing all those possible characters that may trigger the issue and I just tried to make things simple to answer directly what the user ask from his inquiry, but I'm aware that this is prone to SQL injection but I think the person concerned with it already knew it also. ;)

Answer (score 0):

this is `UNTESTED`.

```
insert into game_friends
(
    game_users_id,
    game_users_id_name,
    created_to_app_users_id,
    created_to_app_users_id_name
) 
VALUES
SELECT  game_users_id, 
        created_to_app_users_id, 
        FinalTable.game_users_id_name,
        FinalTable.created_to_app_users_id_name
FROM
    ((SELECT app_users_game_users_id as game_users_id,
           app_users_game_users_id_name as game_users_id_name
    FROM   app_users
    WHERE  app_users_game_users_id = game_users_id) as iGameID
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT app_users_created_to_app_users_id as created_to_app_users_id,
           app_users_created_to_app_users_id_name as created_to_app_users_id_name
    FROM   app_users
    WHERE  app_users_created_to_app_users_id = created_to_app_users_id) as iCreatedID
        ON iGameID.game_users_id = iCreatedID.created_to_app_users_id)  as FinalTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `SELECT` over two tables without any `JOINs` should do the trick (assuming each select statement returns only one row):

```
INSERT INTO game_friends (
    game_users_id,
    game_users_id_name,
    created_to_app_users_id,
    created_to_app_users_id_name
)

SELECT  u_game.app_users_game_users_id,
        u_game.app_users_game_users_id_name,
        u_created.app_users_created_to_app_users_id,
        u_created.app_users_created_to_app_users_id_name
FROM    `app_users` u_game,
        `app_users` u_created
WHERE   u_game.app_users_game_users_id = $game_users_id
    AND u_created.app_users_created_to_app_users_id = $created_to_app_users_id
```

---

Another note: I am guessing that you `app_users` table does really have a column `app_users_game_users_id` or `app_users_created_to_app_users_id`. In which case you should replace those in the SQL with the real column name, which again I guess is either `user_id`, `app_user_id` or `id`. It is just that your model looks very strange otherwise assuming that both of the above mentioned columns are supposed to be unique in the table.

Comment: Also note that you do not need `VALUES` in the `SQL` statement: it is either `VALUES` or `SELECT`